# Pause doesn't work in Timeline Lite

Tags: gsap, timeline.js

I want to slide each element in my div one after the other having some pause after each item slides. Below is my code attached.
    $(function () {

$('.tick').each(function () {

var $self = $(this);

var t1 = new TimelineLite();

t1.to($self, .5, { x: 100, ease: Cubic.easeInOut });

t1.pause();

t1.resume();

});'

what it does is: It slides all the items at a time. It doesn't pause after each item slides... What is the issue in the code?

Thanks & Regards,

Bunnie

Answer (score 0):

```
var delayTween = 0.1;   // your pause time in seconds
var tweenArr = [];

// I have put this line outside of each block because it will re insatiate t1 all the time, and we require to initialise it only once
var t1 = new TimelineLite();

$('.tick').each(function () {

    // var $self = $(this);     
    // there is no need to bind this to jquery object because tweenmax works well with "this" (html element)

    tweenArr.push(
        TweenMax.to(this,0.5,{x:100,ease:Cubic.easeInOut});
    );

});

t1.add(
    tweenArr,
    '+=0',
    "sequance",
    delayTween
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Whats happening is you are calling `pause()` and then your calling `resume()` right after it.

What you can do is just add another `to()` tween and just pass an empty `target` and `vars` object. And then set its `duration` to the pause time you want.

```
// pause timeline for 5 seconds 
t1.to({}, 5, {});
```

Also see: [GreenSock Forum Topic - Inserting a pause delay wait into timeline](http://greensock.com/forums/topic/9856-inserting-a-pausedelaywait-into-timeline/#entry40384)

Hope this helps! :)